# In AnyLogic make a resource (like an operator) "drive" an agent from a TransporterFleet

Tags: anylogic

I would like to know if in anylogic there is a way to show that a resource (in my case an operator) moves together with a transporter taken from a TransporterFleet.

I attach an image of the blocks involved. Basically you have a seize of a resource from the Operator1 resource pool which is sent to the node where the transporter is located (forkliftsHome1). Once arrived, the transporter starts its unloading operation from a Storage (so far so good).
However, when the transporter arrives at its destination and has finished unloading (I have chosen the option that the transporter does not return to its home), the Operator1 resource from the resource pool is freed as it is still on forkliftsHome1. In practice, Operator1 is occupied as I wanted, but in fact the transport is carried out only by the transporter. Is there any way to move them together so that when `Operator1` is released it is on the transporter's location (or on a nearby node)?

this is the image of the blocks I'm talking about: tree blocks I'm interested are `seizeOperator1ForRetrieve` , `retrievePallet` , `releaseOperator1`

[image: this is the image of the blocks I'm talking about: tree blocks I'm interested are seizeOperator1ForRetrieve , retrievePallet , releaseOperator1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is cheating a bit, but if you do not actually need the operator to travel with the forklift, my solution in a similar situation was making the operator invisible while the forklift transports the item, then as a custom wrap-up task I made the operator jump beside the forklift with a moveTo block then made it visible again
([see the process flow pictured here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJUnt.png)). This was possible by connecting the operator and forklift with the 'Link to agents' element, so for the destination of the operator I could obtain the x,y,z coordinates of the forklift.